# Snowflake get all details about Function in one query

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, sql-function

Hi Snowflake community.

I need to get details about Functions that are present in `information_schema.functions` (FUNCTION_SCHEMA, FUNCTION_CATALOG, FUNCTION_NAME, CREATED columns) and full definition like returned by `SELECT GET_DDL('function', 'test_function()')` in one query that is build programmatically.

I don't have function arguments at java code where i build query so i can't simply use `GET_DDL` with joins/unions/innerSelects/whatever. Also `FUNCTION_DEFINITION` column that is present in `information_schema.functions` is not enough.

Is there way to get definition of Function like provided by `GET_DDL` in other way?
Much appreciate your help.

Comment: HI , did you try desc function function_name; , that may help you.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `describe function`. Here is usage from the [documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/desc-function.html)

```
describe function <name> ( [ <arg_data_type> ] [ , ... ] )
```

And if you wish to do something with the output of that function, you can use [result_scan](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/result_scan.html) later on

Comment: ```DESCRIBE``` require knowing function arguments beforehand. Just like ```SELECT GET_DDL```. In my case i need to get details about bunch of functions knowing only their names from Java code in one query. Hoping for something similar to ```SHOW CREATE FUNCTION``` in Mysql

Comment: The behavior is Snowflake is different. Snowflake allows UDFs with duplicate names such that a UDF is not uniqued by name but rather name+arguements.